# change all value of inputs with same id in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change all value of same id inputs?

```
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
```

I use

```
<script>
document.getElementById("secure").value = '123456';
</script>
```

But only first one changes.

```
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="123456">
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="secure" name="secure" value="">
```

Comment: you have to use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: how about same names? @Teemu

Comment: Multiple names will do, but then you'd use `getElementsByName` method to get the elements with the same name.

Comment: Although it is true that ID should not be used more than one time because they are unique and here it is must, but if anyone uses it more times in case he/she don't want to make the element unique, then what problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `id="secure"` to `class="secure"` first

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" class="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="secure" name="secure" value="">
<input type="hidden" class="secure" name="secure" value="">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("secure");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
    // Do stuff here
    el.setAttribute('123456');
});
</script>
```

Comment: That will update only one element. He wants to update all of them.

Answer (score 2):

IDs should be unique - that's the point of them. Classes are for the opposite use, i.e. where there may be multiple instances of a single one.

Assumimg you change your IDs to classes, we can do the following:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.secure'), function(el) {
    el.value = '123456';
});
```

Comment: fyi .. querySelectorAll() has it's own `forEach` also

Comment: I seem to recall browser support is patchy.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use same id multi-pal times. Use class rather then id. To see result I remove `type="hidden"` from your HTML.

```js
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("secure");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
 list[i].setAttribute("value", "12345");
}
```

```html
<input name="secure" value="" class="secure" />
<input name="secure" value="" class="secure" />
<input name="secure" value="" class="secure" />
<input name="secure" value="" class="secure" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class for each elements as **in a document duplicate id's are not allowed**.So we can better keep a common class of our element [also I changed your elements id's for keeping unique]. [**`getElementsByClassName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a nodeList of the DOM. We iterate over the element and put some value. Finally for testing I print value by id.

```html
<input type="hidden" id="secure1" name="secure" value="" class="secure">
<input type="hidden" id="secure2" name="secure" value="" class="secure">
<input type="hidden" id="secure3" name="secure" value="" class="secure">
<input type="hidden" id="secure4" name="secure" value="" class="secure">

<script>
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("secure");
for(var i = 0; i< list.length;i++){
 document.getElementsByClassName("secure")[i].value='123456'
}
console.log(document.getElementById('secure2').value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works - need to reference by class and then loop through all the elements to actually change the value.

```html
<div><input type="text" class="secure" id="secure1" name="secure" value="123456"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="secure" id="secure2" name="secure" value="123456"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="secure" id="secure3" name="secure" value="123456"></div>
<div><input type="text" class="secure" id="secure4" name="secure" value="123456"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    x=document.getElementsByClassName("secure");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].value="100";
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">
click me
</button>
```